# Remotely turning off a router - is it possible?

Tags: home

I'm very sick and have to lie in bed in about 2 months. My router is upstairs in my home and I need a way to turn it off in the evening, when I finish my work (I live alone, but in the morning I have my friend's help, so he could possibly turn on the router for me).

I have a router, Netgear DGN1000 and I'm wondering, if it's possible to turn it off automatically using web interface, or any other method? I've checked the web interface but I can't see the option to turn it off automatically unfortunately. Any ideas how to turn off this router?

Comment: Why do you need to turn it off? Are you removing power to the router or just turning off the signal?

Comment: A more physical solution such a timer on the plug socket? If you can see the router you could use a remote control plug socket.

Comment: IMHO, this question should remove the reference to the router and become "how do I turn off something from far away".  This isn't really the place for a technical question about a specific model of router.

Comment: Someone please explain to me why you need to turn your router off at night? I don't get it....

Comment: Is this your main router or a secondary router/wifi extender? If its a secondary router I can somewhat understand why would you want to turn it off.

Answer (score 4):

*Assuming the router itself does not have a feature to control access times…*

If you want the control to be completely automated (on/off at specific times), you can use an "outlet timer" to cut off the power and turn it back on at whatever times you program. No intervention required.

[image: Outlet Timers]
[**Search Outlet Timers**](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=shop&q=outlet+timer)

If want to *manually* control when you are done for the day, you can plug the device into an "outlet remote" to turn the power off from downstairs. Make sure the model you selected uses an RF signal (not infrared) so the signal will go through the house to the floors upstairs.

[image: Outlet Remotes] [**Search Outlet Remotes**](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=outlet+remote&tbm=shop)

Comment: Note: 'access times' is not the same as switching it off. _My_ router has an '_off_ timer'. I think your outlet devices are the only sure options for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a box on the web interface under 'Wireless settings' -> 'enable wireless radio'.  Check/Uncheck box to turn on/off the signal.

Comment: This doesn't actually turn the thing off.

Answer (score 0):

I have a perfect solution for it which I am using in my house to control the room lights and fan. You can use the same to completely switch off the router. You can control your router (Turn ON & Turn OFF) from your phone but this is more related to `Electronics` which I think you don't want for your problem.

Anyways a better solution is to use a long wire. Plug the one end of the wire to a switch board nearby your place and one end to the cable of your router. Ask you friend to do this for you. Now you can turn off you router from the switch board near you.

Answer (score -1):

Buy yourself one or more extension cords to make the journey from an outlet you can reach to the router.

With that in mind, you could set up a whole network of extension cords to disperse the draw of electricity to multiple circuit breakers.  Then have a bunch of power strips near you to act as on/off switches.  That can get dangerous, so don't go crazy with it.

The safer alternative would be to buy a long Ethernet cable and keep the router near you.  I imagine this would be more extensive though.

Comment: Extension cords to go upstairs?! That is not a feasible solution for the OP,  add I see it

Comment: Why not?  I've used extension cords to power things in the middle of a field.

Answer (score -1):

If you have separate fuses for the other floor (which are situated on the first floor) then you can use their circuit breakers to turn off electricity on the other floor.

I have something like this at home:

[image: fuses]

Yours may be different cause you live in another country.

These circuit breakers are not made for often switching, but they wont damage if you turn off power several times until you are not sick any more.

Of course you have to check if this will turn off electricity for other electric appliances which must work all the time - like refrigerator, home heating system or other.

Comment: It's a good idea, but you shouldn't use these RCBs as switches.

Comment: Yes they are not intended for that, that is why it is a lifehack

Comment: Yeah, well these things could save your life one day. Not really worth messing with it, or telling somebody else to mess with it, for a lifehack.